# How to automatically print PDF files on two printers based on page size?

Tags: pdf, printing

I regularly find myself printing like 10 `PDF documents` , all 1 page per document with various page sizes. For example 5x `A4`, 3x `A3`, 1x `A2` and 1x `A0`.

I want to print all those pages, and not have to manually select the correct printer (normal printer for `A4` and `A3`, plotter for `A2` and `A0`).

Now can I select all `PDF files`, and hit the print button from the windows explorer, but this does not automatically send the files to the correct printer. It sends all files to the default printer.

Is there any way or tool to automatically select the right printer based on the papersize in the PDF?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [commercial tool](http://www.printandshare.info) ([30-day trial](http://www.printandshare.info/download)) that is capable of doing this, not only on the size, but it can also check on how much colour to route the print job (or number of pages).
Example video that does print job routing based on number of pages: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03RbCbBkAL8&list=PLDF2C2AD95B2B2FC2&index=2

Basically you just create a new Printer profile: 
with 2 Printer channels:

- Printer Channel 1 for A4 and A3
- Printer Channel 2 for A2 and A0

Configure each Printer Channel so that only selects the pages that are needed, in this case printer channel 1 only needs to select A4 and A3 pages and print these, others should be deselected and ignored:
[image]

Do the same for the second printer channel. (if your paper format is not in the list, in the General Configuration --> General settings --> Paper, you can define custom paper formats)

Maybe there are other ways to do it, but that is how I would quickly do it.